# Можно ли импортировать не весь класс, а лишь один его метод?

Tags: python, python-3.x, импорт, python-import

Есть файл `module.py` со следующим содержанием:

```
class Calc():
    @staticmethod
    def plus(a, b):
        return a + b
    @staticmethod
    def minus(a, b):
        return a - b
```

Могу ли я в файле с именем main.py с помощью `import` импортировать не весь класс `Calc`, а только одну его функцию, например, `plus()`

Comment: Есть альтернатива: `from module import Calc`
`plus = Calc.plus`, но хотелось бы сразу имень функцию `plus()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
class Calc:

    @staticmethod
    def plus(a, b):
        return a + b

    @staticmethod
    def minus(a, b):
        return a - b


plus = Calc.plus
minus = Calc.minus
```

Для импорта: `from module import plus, minus`